# How to read an encrypted sqlite db in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption

I've been banging my head on this one for a while - I'm not a fantastic coder, but I can only imagine there's a simple solution that I'm missing.   I've been working on some PoC code to create an encrypted SQLite db using the System.Data.SQLite data provider.  I'm writing a basic console app in C# to help myself understand how this works.   Here's my issue.

I can create a new sqlite db with a password in the connection string which (from what I understand) encrypts the database.  Here's the full code:

```
try
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"c:\temp\test.db.sqlite"))
    {
        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"c:\temp\test.db.sqlite");
    }

    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\temp\test.db.sqlite;Version=3;password=abc");
    conn.Open();

    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
    //System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand("create table test (name char(50))", conn);
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    cmd.CommandText = "insert into test values ('my string')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from test";

    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dr.GetString(0));
    }

    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

That seems to work fine...I can create a table, add data to a table and then query the table.  The next time I try running it, I'll make the following change so as to not recreate the table...otherwise, the code should be the same:

```
...

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"c:\temp\test.db.sqlite"))
{
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"c:\temp\test.db.sqlite");
}

System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\temp\test.db.sqlite;Version=3;password=abc");
conn.Open();

//System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand("create table test (name char(50))", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


cmd.CommandText = "insert into test values ('my string')";

...
```

When I run it the second time, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): file is encrypted or is not a database file is encrypted or is not a database
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How do I reopen and use a db that I created and encrypted?

Comment: I don't think you need to use `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile` - if you connect to a file that doesn't exist, it will be created by default. Try removing that call. Maybe it's interfering with the encryption.. (just a guess).

Answer (score -1):

Set password:

```
string conn = @"Data Source=database.s3db;Password=Mypass;";
SQLiteConnection connection= new SQLiteConnection(conn);
connection.Open();
//Some code
connection.ChangePassword("Mypass");
connection.Close();
```

Change password:

```
string conn = @"Data Source=database.s3db;";
SQLiteConnection connection= new SQLiteConnection(conn);
connection.Open();
//Some code
connection.ChangePassword("Mypass");
connection.Close();
```

Connect with password can be done from the connection string:

```
string conn = @"Data Source=database.s3db;Password=Mypass;";
```

or:

```
string conn = @"Data Source=database.s3db;";
SQLiteConnection connection= new SQLiteConnection(conn);
connection.Open();
//Some code
connection.SetPassword("Mypass");
connection.Close();
```